# Spring jpa onetomany returns only one element

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a bidirectional one to many relationship with the spring data jpa but the list annotated with @onetomany always return one element.

Here is the code for my entities(setters and getters omitted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sdk_sdk")
public class SDKEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String version;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "sdk")
@OrderBy("order ASC")
private List<SDKFileEntity> fileEntities;
}
```

And the second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sdk_file")
public class SDKFileEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String fileType;
private Integer sdkId;

public SDKFileEntity() {
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private SDKEntity sdk;
```

I am trying to have a manytoone mapping where the sdkId corresponds to the id from the SDKEntity class.
Whenever I try to get the sdkfiles from the sdkEntity using spring's repository, the size of the list is always 1.

So for example:

```
SDKEntity entity=repository.findOne(foo);
List<SDKFileEntity> files=entity.getFileEntities();
```

here the size of files is 1, I have to delete the first element from the database to obtain the second element.

Comment: May be that only one `SDKFileEntity` is associated with found `SDKEntity entity`

Comment: Show how you add elements for sdkenttity

Comment: the elements were already in the tables before I created the entities

Answer (score 2):

For me the reason here was that a parent entity implemented equals and hashcode
and unfortunately in a way that all existing entities were equal.
And non of the child entities implemented it herself.

So then the @OneToMany relation returned only the first element.

Took me quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

This part of Code looks suspicious

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private SDKEntity sdk;
```

name = "id" it should be actual column name as written in database column name like this

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "VISIT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Visit visitId;
```

Comment: It is actually just called id in my database.

Comment: THen whar about SDKFileEntity table's id ??

Comment: same, also just called id